# iOS : If app is not running in background,calling openURL crashes app on launch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to launch my app to a specific view, from an external url (from email/webpage using link `myapp://sale/1234`).

If the app is not already running in background,app is crashing on launch.

If the app is running in the background, `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` is called perfectly.

Please help me out.

Comment: What does the crash look like? At what line of code? Also, show all the code relevant to app start-up.

Comment: My fault fellas, it was coredata manageObjectContext, which was not created when openUrl is called. I am saving the url if context is not created and calling the openUrl after managedObjectContext is created.  OpenUrls has nothing to do with my crash. it always works as fine... Thanks a lot anyways.

Comment: @NileshUkey Then answer your own question!

Comment: Ok sulthan, doing it now.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault fellas, it was coredata manageObjectContext, which was not created when openUrl is called. I am saving the url if context is not created and calling the openUrl after managedObjectContext is created. OpenUrls has nothing to do with my crash. it always works as fine... Thanks a lot anyways.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed by using the following code

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){            
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        });
    }
```

Comment: This is working. But I don't know how. is it something related to async operation? Can you plz explain?

Comment: @LalitKumar It was cashing because i was calling [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]; before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions finished. You have to wait for the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to finish.

Comment: How you wait didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to finish, because openURL method called automatically after didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ?