# iOS openurl deep link crashes app and device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, deep-linking, openurl

I've set up deep links to work with my app, calling back to the following function in the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation;
```

If the app has previously been opened then you can open a link from Safari, such as:

```
myapp://foo/bar
```

It opens the app without issue and processes the link fine.

However if you kill the app (using the app switcher) and then open the same link from Safari, it will crash the app in the simulator or crash the device on an iPhone 5s running iOS 8.1.3.

But I don't understand why?

I've tried removing the `application:sourceApplication:annotation:` function from the app delegate, and it still crashes if the app is not running. (If it is running it opens the app fine).

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you have in this method? Something with CoreData (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514668/ios-if-app-is-not-running-in-background-calling-openurl-crashes-app-on-launch) ?

Comment: No. And it still happens even when I remove everything bar a simple NSLog statement.

Answer (score 0):

After looking for hours, this worked for me

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){            
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use dispatch_async? My app opens Netflix app and it works fine without dispatch_async. Note that all of my code is on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

Open URL (Deep Link) Update for ios 11

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
    {

        if url.absoluteString.contains("ABC") {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification.init(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "reloadData")))
            return true
        }
        else // facebook
        {
            return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, options: options)

            //return true
        }
        //return true
    }
```